# get all the days of the current week in arabic android

Tags: android, calendar, date-format

I'm using the following code to get the days of the current week

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

    String[] days = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("days of week: "+days[i]);
    }
```

it gives me the days and dates ok, but I want them in arabic, what is the code to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SimpleDateFormat's constructor you can pass in the locale.
new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale);
Setting that to any kind of arabic rooted language should do the trick.

UPDATE: 
Precisely that:

```
//  Arabic available since 2.3
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE yyyy/MM/dd", new Locale("ar"));
```